# Embedded UIScrollView not loading its subviews

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, instantiation

I have perhaps a strange VC structure here that I just made a bit stranger, causing it to break

UIViewController (contains->) UIContainerView (embeds ->) UIScrollView (contains ->) UIView

I have the final UIView because I couldn't figure out how to make the scrollview adhere to certain size restrictions so I just added a "content view".

Problem is, now the "content view's" data isn't loading

The Logs for the contentview are:

```
<UIView: 0x81cd510; frame = (-306 0; 612 792); autoresize = TM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x81c2000>>
```

The Logs for the Scrollview are

```
<UIScrollView: 0x81e5e90; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x81e67b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x81e6060>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
```

so it appears to not be loading... what gives? How to I make it load?

Edit to clarify:

- All of these views were created though IB
- Not using AutoLayouts (although that sounds interesting)
- The NSLog methods are called in ViewDidAppear in the viewcontroller at the top of the view hierarchy chain. (Perhaps this is the issue?)

Edit: uploaded the project to github so that people can take a looksie
https://github.com/Pinwheeler/ChiroMatic.git

Comment: You might have to clarify, perhaps telling us how your created these views (IB or programmatically), whether you're using auto layout or not, when you're examining these `frame` values (e.g. in `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear`, the former often being too early if the view creation process), etc.

Comment: thusly edited good sir (was this comment necessary, or did you receive notification once I edited it?)

Comment: While it's a little cryptic, if you want a full description of the view hierarchy, you can put a breakpoint in `viewDidAppear` and then type the following command into the debugger: `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] recursiveDescription]`. That will show you the full view hierarchy. Anyway, going back to your original question, it's impossible to diagnose what's going on on the basis of what you've shared so far. Perhaps you can compress your project and upload it somewhere for us to take a look at it.

Comment: @Rob, I have uploaded my project to github, the file in which this bit of code appears is PrintViewController.m The scrollview and contentview are both subviews of the VC PrintContentViewController. Edit: I'm a total newbie at gitHub so please if I did something wrong let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spent quite a bit of time going through your project and, frustratingly, I was not able to deduce what was causing the problem. But I found I was able to fix the problem by recreating your `PrintViewController` and `PrintContentViewController` scenes (and I had to recreate both to fix the problem). I created a fork of your project and fixed the two scenes. I tried to annotate my changes in both the source code as well as the git repository commit comments, so hopefully you can follow what I changed. My fork is available at:

- https://github.com/robertmryan/ChiroMatic

(Just let me know when you want me to remove that repo. I'm happy to remove it whenever you want, as I assume you don't want me to leave a copy on github indefinitely.)

A couple of observations:

1. You say that you're not using autolayout, but you are. (Go to the first `Document Inspector` tab on your storyboard and you'll see that "Use Autolayout" is checked.) That's fine if you want to use it (it's now the default in Xcode) but be forewarned that you lose backward compatibility to iOS versions prior to iOS 6 if you use it. Autolayout is powerful, but it can be tricky when you first start using it. It's your call.
2. In your `PrintContentViewController`, my most significant change was to use the standard view controller scene configuration (where the top level view is a `UIView`), and I made the `UIScrollView` a subview of that. Having said that, I don't think you needed the `UIView` subview of the `UIScrollView` (and it's problematic as you lose some scroll view functionality if you have that intermediate `UIView`), so I removed that, and made all of the labels and the like subviews of the scroll view itself.
3. You're using container views all over the place, but it strikes me that you're adding a level of complexity that's unnecessary. (And, by the way, you wouldn't have had the problem raised in your original question if you didn't use these container views.)

   Custom containers are very useful when you want to abstract the logic associated with the container view controller from its child view controller. But you're not doing that here. Worse, you're going through all sorts of gyrations to grab the `IBOutlet` references of a child controller and updating the properties in the container controller. I'd heartily encourage you to reconsider your use of these container views and just excise them from your project entirely.

   If you have a compelling need for the container views, fine use them (I love them and use them all the time), but I don't see any need for it here, and you're making life much more complicated for yourself.

   Also, by the way, the use of the embed segue is an iOS 6 feature only, which can be an issue if you need iOS 5 backward compatibility.

Bottom line, I never was able to reproduce your problem when creating a new project and mirroring your storyboard. Nor was I able to eliminate your problem by any edits to your old `PrintViewController` and `PrintContainerViewController` scenes. I was only able to fix it when I recreated these scenes, and when I did that, it just worked.

I left your old scenes there (prefacing the segues with "old" so the storyboard wouldn't get confused), so maybe you can spend time figuring out what's wrong, but I don't see it. Maybe there was some bug in the storyboard that is evading me. Maybe there's some setting I'm not seeing. All I know is that when I just recreated it, copying your controls to my two new scenes, it just worked.

Personally, I'd advise cutting the Gordian knot, and just eliminate the container views altogether. Your code will be cleaner, and these sorts of issues are less likely to rear their ugly heads.

This isn't a satisfying conclusion (to not know what caused the problem), but at least it appears to be fixed. Good luck.

Comment: I have a not inconsiderable about of love for you right now. I'm seriously just astounded that you would take time out of your day to help me out like that and an upvote and official answer are seriously not enough thanks for your help. As per your suggestions, I'm not married to the embed segue, but I don't seem to be able to just drag out another view on top of my views to mimic the embed segue look. What would you recommend/are there any good resources you could point me to generally that would tell me?

Comment: @Pinwheeler I'm not sure what you mean. Consider the `PrintViewController` scene, just delete the container view from that scene, drag out a scroll view where the container view was, size it appropriately, cut and paste the controls from the other scene into this new scroll view. Once you do that, you can delete that code that manually set all of those properties, `PrintViewController` is greatly simplified, as is the storyboard, and you completely eliminate `PrintContainerViewController`. See the "no-custom-container" branch of my above project.

Comment: Sorry about the lateness of the reply. I'm moving to Florida in a few days and things have been hectic. I downloaded your repo and it works great except for the scrollview apparently doesn't contain all of the labels? When I "scroll" only the report data line moves, none of the other more static text moves. I'll see if I can get this one figured out but just wondering if you knew anything about that and/or if the problem is the same on your end

Comment: okay I figured it out. The scrollview needed to contain the labels as opposed to the default "view".

Comment: @Pinwheeler - Regarding the scroll view bug, that was obviously my mistake introduced when I recreated the view. Sorry. But it sounds like you figured it out. Well done!